# Selecting from objects within objects

Tags: powershell

I have an array of information in Powershell that is comprised of objects within objects.  It goes down 4 objects deep.  Is there a way to select a property from the bottom most object while remaining at the top level?  Does this make sense what I am asking?

```
$result
active                    : active
security                  : @{waf=; acls=}
sealloaction              : 
siteDualFactorSettings    : @{enabled=False; version=0}
login_protect             : @{enabled=False; url_patterns=System.Object[]}
performance_configuration : @{advanced_caching_rules=; acceleration_level=standard; cache300x=False; cache_headers=System.Object[]}

$result.security

waf                      acls                    
---                      ----                    
@{rules=System.Object[]} @{rules=System.Object[]}

$result.security.waf

rules                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
-----                                                                                                                                                                                                                                                            
{@{action=api.threats.action.block_request; action_text=Block; id=api.threats.sql_injection; name=SQL Injection}, @{action=api.threats.action.alert; action_text=Alert Only;}
```

Comment: @wOxxOm Make that an answer. Add some explanation of what's going on. I guess `Where { ... }` is just syntactic sugar for something like `% {if (...) { $_ } }`?

Comment: @wOxxOm We're getting warmer!  I had to change it to `$results | select domain, @{N='rules'; E={($_.security.waf.rules)}}`

This gave me something along the lines of:
`domain : domain.name.com
rules : {@action=api.threats.action.block.....and a lot more}`

Basically, I still need to expand that property, but I cannot expand one without expanding the other and domain is non-expandable.

Comment: `$result | %{ $domain = $_.domain; $_.security.waf.rules | select *, @{N='domain'; E={$domain}}}`

Comment: @wOxxOm That's what I was looking for.  I want to mark that as the answer.  Can you respond as an answer, not a comment?  Thanks.

Comment: Sure. Now that I finally understood the goal :-)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To produce a mixed main/nested level selection:

1. `foreach` on the main array
2. `select` of the nested stuff + calculated properties to reference the iterated main array element

```
$results | ForEach {
    $r = $_
    $r.security.waf.rules | select *, @{N='domain'; E={$r.domain}}
}
```

Or as a one-liner:

```
$results | %{ $r = $_; $r.security.waf.rules | select *, @{N='domain'; E={$r.domain}} }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
$myArray | where { $_.x.y.z -eq 'something' }
```

which is functionally equivalent to

```
foreach ($object in $myArray)
{
    if ($object.x.y.z -eq 'something')
    {
        $object  # Writes $object to the output stream
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Two ways to do the same thing

```
$x = [PSCustomObject]@{
    active   = 'active';
    security = [PSCustomObject]@{
        waf  = [PSCustomObject]@{
            rules = @(
                [PSCustomObject]@{
                    action='api.threats.action.block_request'; 
                    action_text='Block'; 
                    id='api.threats.sql_injection'; 
                    name='SQL Injection'}, 
                [PSCustomObject]@{
                    action='api.threats.action.alert'; 
                    action_text='Alert Only';}
            )
        }
        acls = [PSCustomObject]@{
            rules = @(
                [PSCustomObject]@{
                    action='api.threats.action.block_request'; 
                    action_text='Block'; 
                    id='api.threats.sql_injection'; 
                    name='SQL Injection'}, 
                [PSCustomObject]@{
                    action='api.threats.action.alert'; 
                    action_text='Alert Only';}
            )
        }
    }
}

$x.security.waf.rules | select *, @{name='domain'; ex={'foo'}}

$x | select -ExpandProperty security | select -ExpandProperty waf | select -ExpandProperty rules | select *, @{name='domain'; ex={'foo'}}
```

Answer (score 0):

The easier way should be with `$result | select ${L='label';E={$_.security.waf}}` then you drill down to where you want.

For example:

```
$obj1_child = New-Object -TypeName psobject 
$obj1_child | add-member -Name obj1_child -MemberType NoteProperty -Value "obj1_child"
$obj1_child | add-member -Name value1 -MemberType NoteProperty -Value "child_value1"

$obj1 = New-Object -TypeName psobject 
$obj1 | add-member -Name obj1 -MemberType NoteProperty -Value "obj1"
$obj1 | add-member -Name child -MemberType NoteProperty -Value $obj1_child

$obj2 = New-Object -TypeName psobject 
$obj2 | add-member -Name value1 -MemberType NoteProperty -Value "value1"

$parentObj = New-Object -TypeName psobject
$parentObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name string -value "parentObject"
$parentObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name OBJ1 -value $obj1
$parentObj | Add-Member -MemberType NoteProperty -name OBJ2 -value $obj2


$parentObj | select string,obj2, @{L='value of obj1 child';E={$_.obj1.child.value1}}
```

I create a `$parentObj` inside there's a string, and two objects ($obj1,$obj2), and inside `$obj1` there's another object (`$obj1_child`). Now I want the string from `$parentObj` and the last string from `$obj1_child` this should work:

`$parentObj | select string, @{L='value of obj1 child';E={$_.obj1.child.value1}}`

Output:

```
>> $parentObj | select string, @{L='value of obj1 child';E={$_.obj1.child.value1}}


string       value of obj1 child
------       -------------------
parentObject child_value1
```

Not sure if it's what you want. but it was what I was looking for when landed here, so may help someone else.
Reference: 
https://devblogs.microsoft.com/scripting/access-objects-inside-other-objects-in-powershell-pipeline/